# .htaccess how to redirect the contents of a subdirectory to a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

how can i achieve this If I want to redirect content from `www.mysite.com/subdirectory/image.jpg` to `www.myothersite.com/image.jpg`

but my current .htaccess redirects the content like this `www.myothersite.com/subdirectory/image.jpg`

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule \.(css|js|webp)$ http://myothersite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule inside `/subdirectory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.+\.(css|js|webp|jpe?g)$ http://myothersite.com/$0 [NC,R=301,NE,L]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` represents full URI but `$0` here will have URI part after `subdirectory/`

Comment: Hey @anubhava most images are loading but some content that is loaded in html through root `<img src="/image/photo.png" />` are not loaded only those that are loaded through direct url `<img src="https://www.example.com/subdirectory/image.jpg" />`

Comment: This rule will only affect images that are inside `subdirectory/`. Do you want to apply rule for all the images?

Comment: If you dont mind telling me how to do that, also the images are in the subdirectory/ but are loaded through root img tag

Comment: If you move this rule to site root .htaccess then it will redirect every css, js and image file to new site.